# Видимость всех элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, есть макет (код ниже) из 3 элементов: EditText, RecyclerView, Button. Как сделать, что б высота RecyclerView изменялась в зависимости от содержимого? Т.е. были видны все элементы в RecyclerView.

Если решение известно - киньте, плз, ссылку. Спасибо!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `layout_height="wrap_content"` в самом верхнем `layout`

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но нормально ли это, что RecyclerView лежит внутри ScrollView?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас концепция хромает, т.к. RecyclerView пихать в ScrollView уже дико

Comment: Если вам надо отображать все элементы то используйте ```LinearLayout``` вместо ```RecyclerView ```.

Comment: @АндройдАндройд так сделано для использования в планшетном фрагменте. там RecyclerView с высотой экрана и прокруткой.

Comment: @Barmaley, не работает так. В этом и проблема.

Comment: @dramf Честно, удивлен, что у Вас там вообще что-то прокручивается.

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.